# OPENSHIFT app running slow. Low memory even when app is stopped

Tags: node.js, openshift

My app is running slow after a few days. Using the unix "top" command it seems there is not a lot of free memory. See below. Even if I stop the application about the same memory shows used. Any ideas why? Does this amount of memory look normal with no app running on a small gear application? How can I reboot the virtual machine?

Below is the output of the "top" command with no app running. Shows
7513700k total,  7327484k used,   186216k free

top - 22:06:26 up 14 days,  5:42,  0 users,  load average: 1.83, 2.82, 3.21
Tasks:   3 total,   1 running,   2 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 10.2%us, 26.6%sy,  1.6%ni, 57.4%id,  4.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.2%st
Mem:   7513700k total,  ***7327484k used,   186216k free***,   170244k buffers
Swap:  6249464k total,  4210036k used,  2039428k free,   925320k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 48736 3558      20   0 14908 1176  944 R  0.7  0.0   0:00.04 top
 48374 3558      20   0  102m 2684  848 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
 48383 3558      20   0  106m 2072 1436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.19 bash

Comment: What type of app are you running? 
A

Answer (score 0):

What type of app are you running? Also, since openshift uses cgroups you'll want to see what your usage is within your cgroup (top output shows the whole system). Try including the output from `for i in $(oo-cgroup-read all);do echo “oo-cgroup-read $i” && oo-cgroup-read $i; done` and pay close attention to your memory limits.